# Nested routes in express project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nested-routes

I am new to nodejs/express. I have one requirement to host some nested pages. For example, I have to host some pages like:

```
 http://IP:port/cartoons,
 http://IP:port/cartoons/micky,
 http://IP:port/cartoons/minnie
```

I am able to host cartoons page, by creating app.js with below details:

```
var cartoonRouter = require('./routes/cartoons');
app.use('/cartoons', cartoonRouter);
```

And making the corresponding changes in routes/cartoon.js And it is working fine.  But I am unable to write the same for 'cartoons/micky'.

Could someone help with that?

Comment: weird errors? huh...

Comment: I mean sometimes "NotFound Error" , ENOENT: no such file or directory etc

Comment: Hmm..edited the question..file path is same. But looks like i am unable to write proper code for nested routes :(

Comment: Show us the code you are using for the `/cartoons/micky` route.  We can't help you fix code we can't see.  Your router should be specifying a route for `/micky` because the router is already installed on `/cartoons`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `/cartoons/micky` route is on the cartoonRouter you show in your code, then the router declaration for the micky route should be like this:

```
router.get('/micky', function(req, res) {
    res.send("got micky");
});
```

The router itself is registered on `/cartoons` so any path you put on a route in the router will be added on to the end of `/cartoons`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. This is the piece of code i was looking for. I was doing a mistake, i had created a new js and  a new route "/cartoons/micky" and the was checking with ('/'). Thank you for the help.